# Add class using getElementsByClassName with in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I want to add a class (underline) to each element with rel_row_0 class.

I have this code:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('rel_row_0').classList.add('underline');">X</a>
```

I having this error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Usually I don't use javascript so i'm not that good at it.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a node list. A node list does not have the `classList` property.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('rel_row_0') should return an array. You have to do something like document.getElementsByClassName('rel_row_0')[0] if you have only one element with that class name

Comment: @strek What if I have more than one elements with that class name?

Comment: You would have to do a forEach for all elements and add class name